# Need help understanding a recursion example

Tags: python, recursion

This is an example taken from interactivepython.org. I'm struggling to understand why the function runs the way it does. I understand it moves forward for branchLen, then takes a 20 degree right turn. Then it calls itself and again moves forward(this time branchLen-15) and another right turn. It does this until branchLen is less than 5 and then it stops. So when does the function execute the rest of the code, such as the left turn's for example? I would really appreciate if someone could explain the events of the function chronologically to me.

```
import turtle

def tree(branchLen,t):
    if branchLen > 5:
        t.forward(branchLen)
        t.right(20)
        tree(branchLen-15,t)
        t.left(40)
        tree(branchLen-15,t)
        t.right(20)
        t.backward(branchLen)

def main():
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    myWin = turtle.Screen()
    t.left(90)
    t.up()
    t.backward(100)
    t.down()
    t.color("green")
    tree(75,t)
    myWin.exitonclick()

main()
```

Comment: Have you tried putting in print statements to see what gets executed when? Or follow it through line by line in the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

```
def toZero(num):
    num -= 1
    if num == 0:
        return
    toZero(num)
    num += 1
    return num


def main():
    num = toZero(3)
    print num


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I suggest you a simpler example, try mine for instance but <strike>beware I've never programmed in python it could contain some syntax mistake..</strike> Thanks to salman code syntax is ok now

And do a Trace

main: num=3

```
 |-> toZero(3)

     |-> toZero(2)

           |-> toZero(1)

                   |-> toZero(0)

                         |-> exit

       *note:   num++ <--|

               <--|

        <--|

  <--|
```

*note: when recursion reaches the end, the stack of functions continue from where the point they called itself (because the have a result and can continue).
So the execute the next instruction (num++).

And the final result is... 3